# Рекурсионная функция для вложенных комментариев

Tags: php, mysql

Нуждаюсь в помощи бывалых знатоков) Есть табличка comments с полями: id_comment, id_user, id_news, comment, id_parent, date_time, is_active; и табличка users с полями: id, login и т.д. - всё стандартно.
Есть такой код:

```
public function getComments($id_news)
{
        $sql = "SELECT u.login, c.* FROM comments c
                    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id=c.id_user
                    WHERE id_news='{$id_news}' AND c.is_active=1 
                    ORDER BY id_parent,date_time DESC";

        $result = $this->db->query($sql);

        foreach ($result as $key => $value) {
            if ($value['id_parent'] == 0) {
                $results[$value['id_comment']] = $value;
            } else {
                $results[$value['id_parent']]['childs'][] = $value;
            }
        }

        $results['count'] = count($result);

        return $results;
}
```

Но он считает один уровень вложенности для комментариев. Этот код нужно переписать с использованием рекурсии, а точнее - написать функцию findChildren, которая в качестве параметров будет принимать массив элементов и идентификатор родителя, возвращать функция должна отфильтрованный по идентификатору родителя массив.

Comment: Будете переписывать, запрос к базе в обязательном порядке выносите за рекурсию, чтобы он был выполнен только 1 раз.

Comment: *он считает один уровень вложенности для комментариев* Этот код вообще ничего не считает. Он только выводит комментарии к заданной в качестве параметра новости. *в качестве параметров будет принимать массив элементов и идентификатор родителя* Что за массив элементов? Что за идентификатор родителя? *Этот код нужно переписать* Думаю, что надо не функцию переписывать, а подход менять. И создать на MySQL хранимую процедуру, которая примет исходные данные и вернёт требуемые.